# Backing up GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver

My solution for backing up geoserver is to copy all directories in Tomcat to another disk.

Does a better solution exist for backing up geoserver configuration?

My data is stored in PostGres, if that is relevant.

Backup will be used for recovery settings geoserver.

Comment: This is quite hard to understand, and to the extent that I understand it, is covered in the documentation at http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/data.html - can you try to expand your question to make it easier to see what you are asking?

Comment: Do you want to backup the data, and the configuration together?  Are the data used by applications other than GeoServer?

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question which is worthy of reopening, especially given @RoVo's answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For **normal backup**, you only need to copy the GeoServer data dir and backup the data from your database. All stores, layers, styles and settings are in [that directory](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/datadirectory/location.html).

BUT things might change between GeoServer versions and you should consider a **full backup**. While usually everything will work with newer versions, it might not. To be safe, you also need to copy either the war file and all installed plugins or just copy the deployed GeoServer directory.

I would do a **normal backup** regularly, and a **full backup** for every new installation AND every upgrade.